# AOP: Able to Intercept JDBCTemplate calls but not NamedParameterJdbcTemplate calls

Tags: spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I have made two test methods. One uses JdbcTemplate to make the query while other uses NamedParameterJDBCTemplate.

Using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate:

```
@Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public Student findById(long id) {
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate apptemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        return apptemplate.queryForObject("select * from student where id="+id, Collections.emptyMap(),
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper< Student >(Student.class));
    }
```

Using JdbcTemplate

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


public Student findById(long id) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from student where id=?", new Object[] {
                    id
            },
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper< Student >(Student.class));
}
```

I am using below pointcut to intercept:

For JdbcTemplate:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations+.*(..))")
public void forJdbcTemplate() {
}
```

For NamedParameterJdbcTemplate:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations+.*(..))")
public void forNamedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
}
```

**Why does my pointcut for JdbcTemplate work but pointcut for NamedParameterJdbcTemplate does not work?**

Comment: Because `JdbcTemplate` you use is created by Spring Boot (so can be proxied) whereas the other is created by yourself and cannot be proxied. However Spring Boot creates both so why do you create a new one yourself in the first place, just auto wire it.

Comment: oh ok.. Thank you for pointing out.